# Combine string interpolation and string.format

Tags: c#

I'm just wondering if there is a possibility to combine string interpolation, which was introduced in C# 6.0 and string.format? Any smarter ideas like this?

```
string fancyString = $"My FancyString was created at { DateTime.Now }" + " and I want to add some static with string.format like {0}";
```

Comment: *Why* would you want to do it ? What can you achieve by doing so that is not possible with string interpolation?

Comment: And how would you use it exactly? Pass interpolated string to `String.Format`?

Comment: you bet you can use stringformat after the interpolation like this string.format(fancyString,SomethingToFillYour{0}With);  but why would you ever want to do that?

Comment: Yes, normally string interpolation should do the whole job, but if you don't want to change your whole code from string.format you search for possibilities to combine both.

Comment: Don't think of it in terms of changing code.  By all means use interpolation on new stuff, and convert `string.Format` calls to interpolation during refactoring where appropriate, but changing existing `string.Format` calls to _partial_ interpolation just sounds like making more of a maintenance mess.

Answer (score 17):

Escape your `{0}` by writing it as `{{0}}` so string interpolation leaves it alone. Then you can pass the string into `string.Format` to replace the `{0}`.

For those wondering why you'd want to do this, I can imagine one possibility where you want to do some sort of reusable template such as:

```
var urlTemplate = $"<a href='{BaseHref}/some/path/{{0}}'>{{1}}</a>";

var homeLink = string.Format(urlTemplate, "home.html", "Home");

var aboutLink = string.Format(urlTemplate, "about.html", "About Us");
```

Of course this example is too simple to warrant such a technique, but imagine if you had a template with a very large number of variables and you only cared to change a couple from one rendered template to the next. This would be much more readable than having `{32}, {33}, {34}...` etc. in your template.